# QGIS find the CRS of a map grid with map_get

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, mapping, text

When mapping with QGIS I normally have the main map grid (typically an appropriate UTM zone) as the project CRS.  I also often have a secondary grid with more subtle markings displaying as Lat Longs from the same geographic datum family.  However this can vary by the country and industry of the project as to whether it is WGS84, ETRS89, ED50, or other similar common regional system)

In order to put the CRS in the notes for this system, I would like this to be automated text, so that I do not have to set both the CRS of Grid2 and the text of the note, and potentially mess up.

In fact if I have both grid notes automated from Grid1 and Grid2 it would help highlight any configuration mistakes any user made with a template.

Possibly map_get or another function would do this for me, but I do not know the syntax to get the CRS code and/or CRS description for Grid2 of Map1, where they are neither the project or map CRS.